# Combine several columns into one column when there is only one value per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this df with only one value per column between `y1` and `y4`

```
       x        y1        y2          y3           y4   
0  -17.7 -0.785430       NaN         NaN          NaN 
1  -15.0       NaN       NaN         NaN -3820.085000 
2  -12.5       NaN       NaN    2.138833          NaN
```

I want to combine all y columns in one column `y`.

Edit: Also, I forgot I need another column to tell me which of the 4 y columns the value belongs to.

The output I need is this:

```
       x             y       no   
0  -17.7     -0.785430       y1
1  -15.0  -3820.085000       y4
2  -12.5      2.138833       y3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with groupby, similar to @BENY's:

```py
grouped = df.filter(like='y')
cols = grouped.columns.str[0]
grouper = grouped.groupby(cols, axis = 1)
out = [df.x, 
       grouper.first(), 
       grouper.idxmax(axis=1, numeric_only=True).rename(columns={'y':'no'})]
pd.concat(out, axis = 1)

      x            y  no
0 -17.7    -0.785430  y1
1 -15.0 -3820.085000  y4
2 -12.5     2.138833  y3
```

Another option is to flip it into long form:

```py
df.columns = [f"y_{y}" if y.startswith('y') else y for y in temp]
(pd
.wide_to_long(
    temp, 
    stubnames = 'y', 
    i = 'x', 
    j='no', 
    sep='_', 
    suffix ='.+')
.dropna()
.reset_index()
)

      x  no            y
0 -17.7  y1    -0.785430
1 -12.5  y3     2.138833
2 -15.0  y4 -3820.085000
```

Another option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), where for this particular use case, you want to grab both the column labels and the values:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

# use the original dataframe, 
# with no modifications on the columns
(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = 'x', 
    names_to = 'no', 
    values_to = 'y', 
    names_pattern='(.+)', 
    dropna=True)
) 
      x  no            y
0 -17.7  y1    -0.785430
1 -12.5  y3     2.138833
2 -15.0  y4 -3820.085000
```

The groupby should be faster than the long form approach, since flipping to long form isn't necessary - the lesser the number of rows to deal with, the more performant it should be.

Answer (score 4):

Let us try `groupby` with `first`

```
out = df.groupby(df.columns.str[0],axis=1).first()
Out[60]: 
      x            y
0 -17.7    -0.785430
1 -15.0 -3820.085000
2 -12.5     2.138833
```

Comment: Thank you @BENY. I forgot I needed another column. Can you please check my edit to original question?'

Comment: By the way, what does the 60 in `Out[60]:`  mean?

Comment: @PeterM that is my out queue , you can ignore it ~

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution:

```
df.assign(y = df.iloc[:,1:].sum(axis=1)).dropna(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      x            y
0 -17.7    -0.785430
1 -15.0 -3820.085000
2 -12.5     2.138833
```

Comment: Thank you! Any chance you can help me with the another problem? It's in the edit to my question